# withStyles component wrap

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import SnackbarContent from '@material-ui/core/SnackbarContent';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';

const styles = theme => ({
  error: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.error.dark,
  }
})

class Snack extends React.Component {

  state = {
    opendialog: false,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  test() {
    this.setState({opendialog: !this.state.opendialog});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Snackbar open={this.state.opendialog}>
        <SnackbarContent message="test"/>
      </Snackbar>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Snack);
```

and app main:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Snack from './Snack.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.snack = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleHello}>Hello World</Button>
            <div>
            <Snack ref={ ref => this.snack = ref } />
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleHello = () => {
    this.snack.test();
  }
}

export default App;
```

I get a "TypeError: _this.snack.test is not a function" when I click the button, however if I drop the withStyles the code works correctly.

I'm just replacing "export default withStyles(styles)(Snack);" line with "export default (Snack);".

Why it does not work correctly with the "withStyles"? How can I make it work?

Comment: What is your `@material-ui` version?

Comment: Currently:   "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.3",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4" I've tried a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `withStyles` wraps your component, you need to instead use:

```
<Snack innerRef={ref => (this.snack = ref)} />
```

[withStyles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js) passes the `innerRef` property to the wrapped component as `ref`.

I tried this using the latest version of `@material-ui/core` (currently 3.8.1). I can't guarantee that older versions support this in the same way.

Here's a fully working example:

[image: Edit 91v0klq4n4]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because the `withStyles` HOC return a new component so you are getting the reference of the HOC. You can use `innerRef` prop:

```
<Snack innerRef={ ref => this.snack = ref } />
```

According to the official documentation:

> It adds an innerRef property so you can get a reference to the wrapped component. The usage of innerRef is identical to ref.

You can check it in the official documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component) withStyle function.

I already tested it with your current version it works properly